# min-height:100% doesn't work on my container?

Tags: css

Dear fellow readers on Stack Overflow, I am currently working in CSS and I ran into trouble with giving my container a minimal height of 100% to get my footer at the bottom of the page, and not any higher.

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html,body{
    margin:0;
    padding;0;
    height:100%;
}
body{
    font-family:Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#EFEFEF;
    background:url(../img/bg.jpg);
}
#container{
    width:1150px;
    opacity:0.7;
    background-color:black;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:auto;
}

/* Main Navigation */

#main-nav { height: 50px; }
#main-nav dl { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

/* IE5 Mac Hack \*/ 
#main-nav { padding-left: 11px; } 
/*/ 
#main-nav { padding-left: 11px; overflow: hidden; } 
/* End Hack */

#main-nav dt { float: left; }

#main-nav dt a {
    display: block;
    height: 0px !important;
    height /**/:50px; /* IE 5/Win hack */ 
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#main-nav dt a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -50px;
}

#main-nav dt#about,
#main-nav dt#about a { width: 71px; background-image: url(../img/nav/about.gif); }

#main-nav dt#services,
#main-nav dt#services a { width: 84px; background-image: url(../img/nav/services.gif); }

#main-nav dt#portfolio,
#main-nav dt#portfolio a { width: 95px; background-image: url(../img/nav/portfolio.gif); }

#main-nav dt#contact,
#main-nav dt#contact a { width: 106px; background-image: url(../img/nav/contact.gif); }

body.about dt#about,
body.about dt#about a,
body.about dt#about a:hover,
body.services dt#services,
body.services dt#services a,
body.services dt#services a:hover,
body.portfolio dt#portfolio,
body.portfolio dt#portfolio a,
body.portfolio dt#portfolio a:hover,
body.contact dt#contact,
body.contact dt#contact a,
body.contact dt#contact a:hover {
    background-position: 0 -100px;
}

body.about #header {
    height: 150px;
    background: #db6d16
            url(../img/headers/about.jpg);
}

#header{
    height:150px;
    background:#DB6D16 url(../img/headers/about.jpg);
}
#header h1{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:right;
    margin-top:57px;
    padding-right:31px;
}
#sidebar{
    float:right;
    width:280px;
    line-height:18px;
}
#content{
    margin-right:280px;
    line-height:18px;
}
#footer{
    height:100px;
    clear:both;
    font-family:Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    color:#C9C9C9;
    border-top:1px solid #EFEFEF;
    padding:13px 25px;
    line-height:18px;
    margin-top:-100px;
    position:relative;
}
#footer a{
    color:#C9C9C9;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#footer a:hover{
    color:#DB6D16;
}
#footer #altnav{
    width:350px;
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
}
#main{
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom:100px;
}
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
#content h2{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
#content p{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    padding-bottom:15px;
}
#sidebar .padding, #content .padding{
    padding:25px;
}
```

This is the CSS I use, the effect is: http://picpaste.com/e85f01c1b470e03c36988c1487917add.png
So, if you look at the pic, I want to have the footer (everything below the white line) to be at the very bottom, and everything above the footer (content,sidebar,header,menu) to be connected to the top of the footer.

If more information is needed, please do ask!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Johann Behrens :: Portfolio</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
        <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
        <meta name="MSSmartTagsPreventParsing" content="true" />
        <meta name="description" content="Description" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Keywords" />
        <meta name="author" content="Johann Behrens" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/basis.css" />
    </head>
    <body class="about">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="main" class="clearfix">
                <div id="main-nav">
                    <dl>
                        <dt id="about">
                            <a href="#">About</a>
                        </dt>
                        <dt id="services">
                            <a href="#">Services</a>
                        </dt>
                        <dt id="portfolio">
                            <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                        </dt>
                        <dt id="contact">
                            <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        </dt>
                    </dl>
                </div>
                <div id="header">
                    <h1><img src="img/general/logo_enlighten.gif" width="236" height="36" alt="Enlighten Designs" border="0" /></h1>
                </div>
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <div class="padding">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nullam gravida enim ut risus.
                        Praesent sapien purus, ultrices a, varius ac, suscipit ut, enim. Maecenas in lectus.
                        Donec in sapien in nibh rutrum gravida. Sed ut mauris. Fusce malesuada enim vitae lacus
                        euismod vulputate. Nullam rhoncus mauris ac metus. Maecenas vulputate aliquam odio.
                        Duis scelerisque justo a pede. Nam augue lorem, semper at, porta eget, placerat eget,
                        purus. Suspendisse mattis nunc vestibulum ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="content">
                    <div class="padding">
                        <h2><img src="img/headings/about.gif" width="54" height="14" alt="About" /></h2>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Enlighten Designs</strong> is an Internet solutions provider that specialises in front and back end development. To view some of the web sites we have created view our portfolio.
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            We are currently undergoing a 'face lift', so if you have any questions or would like more information about the services we provide please feel free to contact us.
                        </p>
                        <h2><img src="img/headings/contact.gif" width="98" height="14" alt="Contact Us" /></h2>
                        <p>
                            Phone:   (07) 853 6060
                            <br />
                            Fax:     (07) 853 6060
                            <br />
                            Email: <a href="mailto:info@enlighten.co.nz">info@enlighten.co.nz</a>
                            <br />
                            P.O Box: 14159, Hamilton, New Zealand
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#">More contact information…</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <div id="altnav">
                    <a href="#">About</a> - <a href="#">Services</a> - <a href="#">Portfolio</a> - <a href="#">Contact Us</a> - <a href="#">Terms of Trade</a>
                </div>
                Copyright &copy; Johann Behrens
                <br />
                Powered by <a href="http://www.mijndomein.nl">Mijn Domein</a> and designed by <a href="http://www.jbehrens.nl">Johann Behrens</a>.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What would be handly would be a snippet of your html laying out everything up to the `#container` element but it is likely your container is in an element that doesn't have a defined height.

Comment: I have edited the post and included the HTML. ;)

Comment: I see you found your answer. As a sidenote; you have the `#container` set to an opacity of 70%. While this is nice you should probably look into rgba backgrounds and the filter property to support IE http://nickcowie.com/2009/rgba-backgrounds-in-ie/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to put your footer at the bottom of the page you can either position:absolute;bottom:0; or http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

http://jsfiddle.net/CP6Qk/

Comment: Dear George, I have tried your first link (css-tricks) but unfortunately, it didn't produce any change in my design. The second link (absolute/bottom) also didn't work for me.
I am sorry!

Comment: I will put it online for you, if you give me 2 minutes, I'll have a link for you!

Comment: basis.css , line 107, change 'relative' to 'absolute' , also set width:1100px; (you don't need clear:both)

Comment: I can't upvote it, I've got a lack of reputation, haha, but I picked it as THE answer. :P

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your parent to a fixed height.

See this article: http://www.search-this.com/2007/02/05/css-min-height-explained/