# CSS, sticky footer

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I know, I know, I asked this question before. Unfortunately, I lost my work. I started over and I came back to my old post ([min-height:100% doesn't work on my container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860888/min-height100-doesnt-work-on-my-container#comment12571607_9860888)) and couldn't remember what the trick actually was.

So I will post the link to my "experiment" here and I hope that you guys (or girls) can help me out, the problem is: I want the footer to be at the very bottom and the content and the two sidebars to connect to the top of the footer. (Also, the scrollbars have to disappear, haha)

http://www.jbehrens.nl/test/index.html

If anyone's able to help me, it's very much appreciated!

Comment: "Unfortunately, I lost my work. I started over..." ever hear about [DropBox](http://db.tt/BxYnhOA)?

Comment: "Unfortunately, I lost my work. I started over..." You should use git.

Comment: I have, however, this doesn't really help me on getting the footer done. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Set the footer to have

```
position: fixed
bottom: 0
```

And then set a height for your side bars and content pane and you might want to set

> overflow: scroll

for the side bars and the content pane.

Comment: Hmm, my design is still looking the same, unfortunately. :(

Comment: ErJab is right here. Look at this to see why yours is broken. http://jsfiddle.net/2rCWG/

Comment: Okay, I tried it again and it looks better now. The text in the div inside the footer-div isn't placed inside the footer?

[link](http://jbehrens.nl/test/)