# Overlapping blocks with CSS sticky footer + 960 grid layout

Tags: css, sticky-footer, 960.gs

I downloaded [CSS sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/) and [960 grid system](http://960.gs) code.

The sticky footer works as expected - if content pane is empty, the footer sticks to bottom of viewport and the footer is pushed down when it is full.

I am using the css sticky footer code with the 960 grid system, but when the content inside the sidebar expands and reaches the footer, the footer overlaps the end of the sidebar content:

http://noseyparka.me.uk/sandbox/

Any idea where I am going wrong and how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're misusing StickyFooter, your wrapper is missing a definition for an additional level to protect the body-content from overlapping the footer.

to solve it, add the `main` id to the body-content level (which is the 960gs container in our case) to accommodate:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="container_12" id="main">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Reference:**

- [StickyFooter's HTML structure](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/html-code.html)

Comment: I *cannot* understand how I missed that. Thank you very much, Eliran - you are a star!

Answer (score 0):

If you add a margin-bottom to your container like this

```
.container_12 {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    }
```

This will compensate for the `#footer` having `margin-top: -100px`

Comment: This works approach solves overlap issue, but it also pushes the footer outside viewport producing a scrollbar, which defeats the purpose of using the sticky footer in the first place.

Comment: what's `minus-top`? did you mean `top: -100px;`?

Comment: Sorry that was an oversite. Should have been margin-top:  -100px; I think I was creating my own CSS there. Never a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The link seems fine.  Seems like you fixed it. And it has the css embedded in the footer that I was going to suggest: clear:both.

Comment: [Adobe BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com) says different. The issue is visible in all browsers, including [Chrome 18.0 on Windows](https://plus.google.com/photos/108735620143428586952/albums/5746171328943648017?authkey=CIS3ysXd2KOVDQ).

Comment: Oy vey! You're right, it didn't come out in other browsers. Only in FF. After going through your sticky footer link ... came across some specs. Try adding padding-bottom:100px to your #wrap. It should work. Here's the thing, whatever your negative margin-top is in footer, it has to match the padding-bottom for #wrap. Otherwise, it'll overlap. Hope this works!

Comment: Once again, this approach solves overlap issue, but it pushes footer outside viewport producing a scrollbar, which defeats purpose of using a sticky footer in the first place in my opinion.

Comment: But that's what your sticky page link says to do. They say to make sure that padding-bottom in #main should match the negative top-margin in #footer. If padding-bottom:100px doesn't work, tweak with the number till it works for you. Also, I'm beginning to wonder about the concept of sticky footer here.  You seem to want one that will always stay in line of sight while the page is being scrolled down, yes? Because the sticky footer page that you provided doesn't do that. And their page is a testimonial to that (ie, footer doesn't stay in viewport while page is being scrolled down). Confused now

Comment: Sorry for being so talkative on this! However, if you want your footer to literally stay in sight the whole time regardless of the status of the page, you don't use this, I think. You make the footer's position fixed. Like this example I googled right now: http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position or even this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465250/css-sticky-footer.

Comment: No not looking for footer to stay in sight at all times, you're missing my point. Your original `padding-bottom:100px` fix worked, but the problem is that when content panes are empty, the footer appears below the viewport. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I see what you mean. (First time I've ever learned that I could delete nodes with developer's tool in chrome!). Is this really a necessary issue to worry about? Will your content panes be ever that empty? Anyway, here's a possible solution. Tried this in chrome with all nodes deleted, and it seems to still keep the footer in view, I think. Put padding-bottom:100px in class container_12. When I did that, the footer was in view the entire time in chrome (and this is with all the content nodes deleted). Hope this helps, and if it doesn't, I give up! (don't do my earlier solution. just this one)