# CSS - Horizontally splitting a page in half

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have a page divided in half, horizontally. I want to accomplish it just by HTML/CSS and I'd prefer not to use JS.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

### CSS

```
#container {
min-height:100%;
}

#top_div {
height:50%;
width:100%;
background-color:#009900;
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
}

#bottom_div {
height:50%;
width:100%;
background-color:#990000;
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="container">

<div id="top_div">top</div>    
<div id="bottom_div">bottom</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding body, html{height:100%}?

Comment: try to give the body and html a height of 100%. `body,html{height: 100%;}`

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
body, html, #container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: +1 Works. Do you know why min-height doesn't force a height of 100%?

Comment: @Matt It get's the height of 100% of the parent container, but the parent (in this case the body) doesn't have a height of 100%. Except some versions of IE.

Comment: Hmm, but the CSS you posted should set the height of the parent to 100%, and it does. I'm just wondering, why do you need to set the height for #container when you're already setting the min-height? http://jsfiddle.net/TQQWV/

Comment: @Matt I isn't my solution... My one is an other. But, I see in your fiddle what you mean. Hmm, don't know yet...

Comment: Hmm, this is weird. In the fiddle without #container the two children don't have the correct height. But the Chrome inspector shows that the container's height is 100% (highlighting the complete iframe). When I set height: 100% on the container the two children expand.

Comment: @Matt I think, to set the height or min-height to 100% is not the best solution. Because some older IE doesn't interpret that correctly. Normally { height: 100%; } means, that 100% of the parent-container is user for the element. IE sometimes uses the window-height instead. Therefore you can set the container { position: absolute; } and { top, left, right, bottom } to zero. The element is now anchoring at the window-borders. It has height and width of 100%.

Comment: @Matt see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860888/min-height100-doesnt-work-on-my-container

Comment: @Matt, that is a very good question...IE9, Opera, Firefox, and Chrome all refuse to display it with `min-height`, which is suggestive (but not proof) that they're compliant with the specs. With that said, I can't quite wrap my head around what that spec might be!

Answer (score 7):

try to change your first CSS-block for `#container` like this

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

than the container has window-height and window-width...

For a better solution do the same with the top and bottom elements inside the container. Set them to position and all top, left,... properties to zero. For the top element set bottom to 50% and for the bottom element set top to 50%.

```
#top_div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    background-color:#009900;
    text-align:center;
}

#bottom_div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:#990000;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/algorhythm/EKB3u/3/)

Comment: BTW for anyone attempting an asymmetrical split e.g. 80% top / 20% bottom: `#top_div { bottom: 20% }` and `#bottom_div { top: 80% }`.

Answer (score 4):

**Viewport units!** Yes, viewport units. [Supported by all browsers since IE9](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), doesn't require you to set `height: 100%` to every parent container.

Adding the property `height: 50vh;` will simply size it to 50% of the `v`iewport `h`eight.

```css
.top {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.bottom {
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class='top'></div>
<div class='bottom'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right then here is what you are trying to do:- Create two column page.

Just take one div element as parent and two child div elements, assign position:relative to parent as this will make it container and position:absolute to children elements,use width to assign specific area.