# Layout with two row - fixed top and scrollable bottom one

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to split a div container to two vertical parts `60%`, `40%`.

my top div (which is `60%`) should always be visible. And my bottom div (`40%`) should be scrollable if items exceeds its limit.

The best I could get is based on this: algorithm's JSFiddle taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14201594/css-horizontally-splitting-a-page-in-half). But after wasting a lot of time im unable to achieve my goal.

I'll attach an image for illustration:

[image]

Comment: Could you set up a JSFiddle showing your closest effort?

Comment: I was about to, but @Hashem Qolami solved my problem too quick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `absolute` positioning for each section and use `top`/`bottom` properties to position the absolutely positioned sections properly.

In this case, the top section sticks at the top of the page by `top: 0;` and the value of `top` property of the `#bottom` element is set to `60%` where the `60%` is the height of the `#top` element. `top: 60%;` declaration forces the `#bottom` to be positioned below the `#top`.

Also in order for `#bottom` to be scrollable, you could use [`overflow-y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) or [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property with value of `auto` for that element.

> **[11.1. The ‘overflow’, ‘overflow-x’ and ‘overflow-y’ properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow)**
>
> These properties specify whether content is clipped when it overflows
>   the element's content area. `overflow-x` determines clipping at
>   the left and right edges, `overflow-y` at the top and bottom edges. `overflow` is a shorthand. If it has one keyword, it sets both `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` to that keyword.
>
> **`auto`** The behavior of the ‘auto’ value is UA-dependent, but should cause a scrolling mechanism to be provided for overflowing
>   boxes.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mojovasi/1/edit)**

```css
#top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
}

#bottom {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, You have definitely solved my problem!! I was wasting the last hour with that errm.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should be something like this (only for an example):

```
<div class="ColumnContainer">
    <div class="FixedItem">
        Fixed
    </div>
    <div class="ScrollContainer">
        <div class="ScrollContent">
            <ul>
                <li>item 1</li>
                <li>item 2</li>
                <li>item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The key here is the CSS:

```
.ColumnContainer {
    position:relative;
}

.ScrollContainer {
    position:relative;
    height:200px; /* must set fixed height */
    overflow:auto;
}
```

By setting a fixed height on the container, and having a single child with all the content pieces as its children, it will force scrolling when it overflows.

[Here is a jsFiddle as an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/etVLa/2/)